# Looking documentation on idlelib.tooltip import Hovertip

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

The following code is from some code I stumbled upon.  It works fine when implemented in larger programs, but I suspect there are more methods/functions available in this library.  As well, I suspect that there may be other parameters for Hovertip than just the anchor_widget, text, and hover_delay - like word wrap length etc.  I have been unsuccessful finding any documentation.  So question is: Does any know what else might can be done with idlelib.tooltip or any more parameters to Hovertip?

```
import tkinter as tk
from idlelib.tooltip import Hovertip

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('100x75')
b1 = tk.Button(root,text='Click Button 1')
b1.pack(pady=20)
Hovertip(anchor_widget=b1,text='Button 1 ToolTip',hover_delay=None)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Using `dir(Hovertip)` will return 7 options. Giving a name to `Hovertip` will return 17 options. Try this `[print(x) for x in dir(tip) if not(x.startswith('__'))].clear()` where `tip` is the name I've given to `Hovertip` instance.

Comment: It is easy to find out if you look into the source code of [`idlelib.tooltip`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/idlelib/tooltip.py). Or you can call `help(Hovertip)` after importing `Hovertip`.